# One readline statement?

Tags: c#

Hey guys this is the code that I have so far but I am trying to find a way where I dont have so many swich statements and where I can only have one readline statement instead of 2 different cases of switch statements.

```
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give me a number");
        switch (c)
        {
            case 0:
                a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                break;

            case 1:
                b = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
        }
    }


   Console.WriteLine("{0}",a+b);
   Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe simply?

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

`Console.ReadLine()` is a blocking call, so the code will wait for the next input.
Also note, that `int` in c# is 32 bit, so you should convert `ToInt32` if you don't want to loose anyting :)

Comment: The thing is that I want to find a way in which I only use the console.reaadline statement once.

Comment: @user249240: one `ReadLine` vs `for` loop with two iterations? Is this a kind of joke?

Comment: @user249240 than it's unclear what are you trying to achieve. Your code will expect two inputs. Please describe your task in words.

Comment: int a = 0;
            int b = 0;


            for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Give me a number");

                int h = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (c)
                {
                    case 0:

                        a = h;

                        break;

                    case 1:

                        b = h;

                        break;
                }
               
            }


           Console.WriteLine("{0}",a+b);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

Comment: @user249240 I see your code, I don't know what you are expecting as result

Comment: @user249240: do you want to assign the same value(from console.ReadLine()) to all variables?

Answer (score 2):

```
int inputs[] = {0, 0};

for(int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
  Console.WriteLine("Give me a number.");
  inputs[index] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}", inputs.Sum());
```